# How to make trigger to work on just recent record being inserted?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

So I am writing a trigger that will check the amount entered and will display the information.

```
Create trigger Trigoninsertpenalties
ON PENALTIES
after insert
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT AMOUNT,
CASE

    WHEN AMOUNT > 30 THEN 'The quantity is greater than 30'
    WHEN AMOUNT = 30 THEN 'The quantity is 30'
    ELSE 'The quantity is under 30'
    END AS PENALTIES
FROM PENALTIES

End
```

The issue is when I am inserting a new record, as a result, I am getting all the rows of the "Amount column" being displayed. I just want that trigger to work on the new record which I inserted and display the result for that only. Please help. Inserting new record query!

```
Insert INTO PENALTIES
VALUES (101,104, '08-03-1998',50)
```

Comment: SELECT AMOUNT,
CASE

    WHEN AMOUNT > 30 THEN 'The quantity is greater than 30'
    WHEN AMOUNT = 30 THEN 'The quantity is 30'
    ELSE 'The quantity is under 30'
    END AS PENALTIES
FROM inserted

Comment: When writing triggers, you should be referencing the `inserted`/`deleted` psuedo tables. Yours isn't, so it'll effect **every** row in the tables; regardless of it was effected or not in the DML statement.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah! I got it! Thanks

Comment: NO NO NO. Triggers should NEVER attempt to return resultsets.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @SMor, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#returning-results) states "The ability to return results from triggers will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Triggers that return result sets may cause unexpected behavior in applications that aren't designed to work with them. Avoid returning result sets from triggers in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently do."

Comment: And please don't use images for code or data... use formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your trigger to use `INSERTED`:

```
Create trigger Trigoninsertpenalties
ON PENALTIES
after insert
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT AMOUNT,
CASE WHEN AMOUNT > 30 THEN 'The quantity is greater than 30'
     WHEN AMOUNT = 30 THEN 'The quantity is 30'
     ELSE 'The quantity is under 30'
END AS PENALTIES
FROM INSERTED

End
```